# XAMPP + .htaccess - rewriterule not working

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess

So I have the following structure :

`xampp/htdocs/project/`
`xampp/htdocs/project/index.php`
`xampp/htdocs/project/api/index.php`

and the following .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/.* /api/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

I believe that what this is saying is to redirect whatever request under api/ to api/index.php.

An AJAX request for api/ brings me the results of api/index.php
An AJAX request for api/user gives me a 301 and then the directory tree of api/user/
An AJAX request for api/user/ gives me a 404.

I then commented out the lines of the .htaccess and the same thing happened. As if it didn't make any difference that the file was there.

What could be wrong? My .htaccess is under `xampp/htdocs`.
I've been fiddling about with this for about 3 hours and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: What is your document root? Doesn't look like you're accounting for the project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your .htaccess in the root of your project, not in htdocs.